# In Spring framework can we write jdbc in jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

Hello friends i want to know whether writing jdbc connection in jsp is it a good way or not in spring frame work.

Comment: Its not a good way. You are breaking the MVC pattern.

Comment: You can, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Looks like I am back in 1996 and not 2013

Comment: in my web application i am dynamically changing the values on a click so i want to do it using jdbc in jsp .

Comment: never put jdbc in jsp, bad practice. this has nothing to do with spring framework, it is bad practice in general.

Comment: with out using jdbc in jsp can i render a page dynamically. i am new to spring please provide a example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not it's not a good way.

This is really a bad design. You are using spring-mvc so I guess you are using the MVC pattern. In the MVC pattern the V(iew) is your jsp and the only responsability of the view is to display a M(odel). This M(odel) comes from the C(ontroller) and must not be built/fetched from the View.

More information on the MVC pattern : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller